# Table with different horizontal alignments

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx

I would like to have a simple table with three columns, where the first is left aligned, the second one is center aligned, and the last one is right aligned. For this I am trying to use `tabularx` but I can't manage to get it to work. This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\raggedright}m{0.33\linewidth}>{\centering}m{0.33\linewidth}>{\raggedleft}m{0.33\linewidth}}
{\Large First Author} & {\Large Second Author} & {\Large Third Author} \\
{ First Institution, which can be very long} & {Second Institution, which can also be very long} & {Third Institution, which can be very long as well and I need to prevent hyphenation} \\
\href{mailto:first@author.net}{first@author.net} &  \href{mailto:second@author.net}{second@author.net}  & \href{mailto:third@author.net}{third@author.net}  \\ 
\end{tabularx}


\end{document}
```

The institutions are long, and so I can't have them hyphenated. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should:

- not use `tabularx` without a `X` column (here you don't need one)
- use `\arraybackslash`
- maybe reduce your column width as it may add up to something greater than textwidth

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{0.33\linewidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.33\linewidth}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{0.33\linewidth}}
{\Large First Author} & {\Large Second Author} & {\Large Third Author} \\
{ First Institution, which can be very long} & {Second Institution, which can also be very long} & {Third Institution, which can be very long as well and I need to prevent hyphenation} \\
\href{mailto:first@author.net}{first@author.net} &  \href{mailto:second@author.net}{second@author.net}  & \href{mailto:third@author.net}{third@author.net}  \\ 
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

---

Alternatively you can use `tabularx` (advantage: automatic column width), but then using a redefined column type `X`:

[image: tabularx]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\renewcommand*{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X>{\centering\arraybackslash}X>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
{\Large First Author} & {\Large Second Author} & {\Large Third Author} \\
{ First Institution, which can be very long} & {Second Institution, which can also be very long} & {Third Institution, which can be very long as well and I need to prevent hyphenation} \\
\href{mailto:first@author.net}{first@author.net} &  \href{mailto:second@author.net}{second@author.net}  & \href{mailto:third@author.net}{third@author.net}  \\ 
\end{tabularx}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```